# Rails scope - how to return instances where their children match a certain value exclusively?

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I write a rails scope that returns all instances of `Company` where its `Employees` status are ALL `'active'` ?

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  STATUS = ['active', 'busy', 'inactive'] 

  belongs_to: :company
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many: :employees
end
```

I tried the following scope :

```
scope :with_active_employees_only, -> {
    select("DISTINCT ON (companies.id) companies.*")
      .joins(:employees)
      .where("employees.status NOT IN (?)", Employee::STATUS - ['active'])
  }
```

But it still returns me Companies where some of the employees are `'busy'` or `'inactive'`, even though I only want companies where its employees are exclusively `'active'`. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: `Company.where.not(id: Employee.select(:company_id).distinct.where.not(status: 'active'))` Select the companies by id that are not in the list of company ids for employees with a status that is not active.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the latest `6.1.x` version of activerecord, you can use `where.missing` with an aptly built association:

```
class Company
  has_many :inactive_employees, -> { where(status: 'inactive') },
           class_name: 'Employee', inverse_of: nil

  # includes companies with no employee at all
  scope :without_inactive_employees, -> {
    where.missing(:inactive_employees)
  }
end
```

If you are not there, you can still backport it from https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L71-L80

Answer (score 0):

you could group employees by company then count all status in which `active` is 1 otherwise 0, so that the company which has all employees active is the one has the status-count is 1.

```rb
    scope :with_active_employees_only, -> {
      Company.joins(:employees)
      .select("companies.*")
      .group("companies.id")
      .having("SUM(CASE WHEN employees.status = 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1")
    }
```